# Any way to generate WSDL documentation from Javadoc with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, documentation, wsdl, jax-ws, wsgen

I'm hoping that an extension of some kind is available that does this (although I suppose that my hope is foolishly optimistic).

```
   /**
     * <p>
     * Gets the {@link ResultObject} given the identifier. The following
     * fields are not available for some users and will contain a null value:
     * </p>
     * 
     * <ul>
     * <li>{@code resultObject.comment}</li>
     * <li>{@code resultObject.anotherObject.actionById}</li>
     * <li>{@code resultObject.anotherObject.actionByName}</li>
     * </ul>
     * 
     * <p>
     * The {@code daysInPurgatory} value will be {@code -1} when not
     * applicable
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param requestUser
     *            the user initiating the request
     * @param identifier
     *            the id of the ResultObject
     * @return the {@link ResultObject} or {@code null} if none exists
     * @throws SomeException
     *             if the {@code identifier} is {@code null}
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "resultObject")
    public ResultObject getResultObjectById(
     @WebParam(name = "RequestUser", header = true, partName = "RequestUser") final String requestUser,
     @WebParam(name = "identifier") final Long identifier)
     throws SomeException;
```

Thanks,
LES2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may look at [Enunciate](http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/). It's possible to use [it's Maven plugin](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Executables#maven) to generate static HTML files from Javadoc comments. This works for SOAP (i.e. JAX-WS) and REST (i.e. JAX-RS) endpoints.

Interesting reads:

- https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Documentation-Only
- http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/my_experience_with_java_rest

Production Examples:

- http://www.realtybaron.com/api/
- http://www.agentrank.com/api/
- http://api.setlist.fm/docs/index.html

Comment: Enunciate moved to [github](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/User-Guide) but is none the less pretty sweet!

Answer (score 8):

You're not the only one looking for a way to generate WSDL documentation (see the [Generating WSDL documentation from Javadoc](http://markmail.org/message/u7xkyc45kqygbcu3) thread) but, AFAIK, there is no **standard** JAX-WS way for doing this.

Now, maybe have a look at JBoss proprietary annotation `@Documentation` mentioned in [JBWS-1850](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1850) that generates `jaxws:binding` artifacts described in section [2.9 Javadoc Customization](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/customizations.html#2.9_Javadoc_customization) when using Java->WSDL approach as well. It's not exactly what you asked for but it might give you some ideas.

In any case, I guess that this would require providing your own `WSDLGeneratorExtension` to extend `wsgen` and generate the desired WSDL.

Comment: @LES2 Huh? Well, I don't know (and that's very sad for me because there was a bounty on this question if I remember well :). Maybe mail team@stackoverflow.com or open a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com to mention the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In one project we published a lot of WSDLs. For every Web Service we have exposed a WS method "getDocumentationURL()". This method deliver back a link to the JavaDoc generated from the SEI. The JavaDoc was place on a accessible intranet server.