# Documenting EJB3 Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, documentation, comments, ejb-3.0

I have a simple web service as below

```
/**
 * Test web service
 */
@Stateless
@WebService
public class HelloWorldWebService {

  /**
   * Greets the user by appending 'Hello' before the name
   */
  @WebMethod
  public String doWork(String name){
      return "Hello " + name + " !";
  }
}
```

Is there a way (using annotations or otherwise) of adding comments to the Web Service or Web Method so that when a third party calls it (or inspects the WSDL), there are comments/documentation that describes the web service, its methods and parameters; much like comments that are later included in java docs.

I think this is [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181841(VS.90).aspx) (last comment) for .NET web service, but not sure in Java web services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to generate WSDL documentation from Javadoc with JAX-WS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746199/any-way-to-generate-wsdl-documentation-from-javadoc-with-jax-ws)

Comment: exploring http://enunciate.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the [lack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746199/any-way-to-generate-wsdl-documentation-from-javadoc-with-jax-ws/2309914#2309914) of standard way of generating the doc, we went the [enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) way.

Plays [really](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Documentation+Only) well with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<wsdl:documentation>` elements to the wsdl: [WSDL Document Structure](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_document-s)