# Generate <wsdl:documentation> tags from Java

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

my application is a Web Service where the wsdl file is generated starting from Java classes. I'd like to add also `<wsdl:documentation>` tags automatically to my wsdl file, so that I can have a sort of "user guide" in the wsdl, so I need to generate these tags starting from Java classes. 
Which is a way to do this?

Comment: Please include some details about how your WSDL is generated.  For instance, do you run a command?  Maven plugin?  wsgen?  Axis?

Comment: I only use JAX-WS tags to make my service run and the project is built with Ant. I see the WSDL via url, just typing http://myaddress/service?wsdl

Comment: This isn't the exact same question but maybe the answers will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746199/any-way-to-generate-wsdl-documentation-from-javadoc-with-jax-ws